# Issue with alignment in LaTex

Tags: errors, align

I just started using LaTeX, and have run into a bit of an error. Here is the document as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
%preamble%

\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{An Introduction to Functions and their Derivatives}
\author{Purple Bat}
\date{September 4th, 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\section{Functions}
In mathematics, a function is often described as \(f(x)\) or \(g(x)\), where \(x\) is the input value.

For example: \[f(x) = x+2\]
\[g(x) = x\]

By assigning a value to x, we can plug it into the function, and come up with a value. Hence,

\[f(x) = x+2,\ x=3\]

Thus, by plugging the x-value into the function, we get:
\[f(3)=3+2\]
Thus,

\begin{align*}

&=3+2\\

%

&=5

\end{align*}

By plugging in the same x-value for \(g(x)\), we get:
\[g(3)=3\]

There is a third function, \(h(x)\), which can be defined by \[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\]
Utilizing the previously defined functions \(f(x)\) and \(g(x)\), we can define \(h(x)\) as:

\begin{align*}

\(h(x)\)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\\

%

 &= \frac{x+2}{3}

%

\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

Now, here's the weird part: The first set of aligned equations compiled with no problem. It's the second set where I run into an error. With the exception of the added comment break (for ease of reading), both alignments are the same. So why is the first one compiling and not the second?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) First, you can't have blank lines in equations (but I suppose that you inserted those just for the markup). The error then is because of the `\(h(x)\)` in the second `align*`. `align*` already enters math-mode, so you don't have to (can't) open path mode with `\(...\)`. Use `h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}` and it'll work :)

Answer (score 1):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

As Phelype Oleinik already said in the comments: You can't have blank lines in equations without at least adding a `%` to comment it out.

I changed your code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%preamble%

\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{An Introduction to Functions and their Derivatives}
\author{Purple Bat}
\date{September 4th, 2018}

\begin{document}

\section{Functions}
In mathematics, a function is often described as \(f(x)\) or \(g(x)\), where \(x\) is the input value.
For example: 
\begin{gather*}
    f(x) = x+2\\
    g(x) = x
\end{gather*}
%
By assigning a value to x, we can plug it into the function, and come up with a value. Hence,
    \[f(x) = x+2,\ x=3\]
%
Thus, by plugging the x-value into the function, we get:
    \[f(3)=3+2 = 5\]
%
By plugging in the same x-value for \(g(x)\), we get:
    \[g(3)=3\]
%
There is a third function, \(h(x)\), which can be defined by \[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\]
Utilizing the previously defined functions \(f(x)\) and \(g(x)\), we can define \(h(x)\) as:
%
\begin{align*}
    h(x)&=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\\
    &= \frac{x+2}{x}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

In the `align*` environment, you use the "column separator" `&` once  (in the second "row"). To let LaTeX know, what should be aligned, you have to add one to the first line too.

I want to add something else: By separating every line of text with a blank line, you will get a pretty ugly appearance (due to the indentation with every new paragraph!) That's why I added the `%`!

Comment: The two consecutive equations, after “For example” should be a single `gather*` environment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I changed it. (I wasn't really paying attention to this part, to be honest)